# Dax to show data from latest available date of every week

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm receiving data 2 or 3 times a week, and I have a line chart to display the data. The ask is that I have to consider latest available data of the week for the chart.
Example:
Let,
Week A be dates from 7th March to 13th March.
Week B be dates from 14th March to 20th March.
In A, I have data on 10th and 13th only and in B, I have data on 14th, 16th and 18th.
Now, in this chart I have to display data from max date from week A that is 13th march and 18th from week B.
I'm not able to write a Dax for this.
Please help.

Comment: Not possible: Week A is 7th March to 13th March and doesn't contain 15th of March.

Comment: Sorry, I'll edit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a **calculated table** to get the data for your line chart:

```
Latest week date = 
SUMMARIZE(
    'Table',
    'Table'[Week],
    "Date", MAX('Table'[Date]),
    "Value", CALCULATE(
        MAX('Table'[Value]),
        'Table'[Date] = MAX('Table'[Date])
    )
)
```

[image]